# Cannot access to dom tree after dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Welcome
I have a problem with landing in jquery.
I remove all from the div using a empty() or remove() functions.
The problem is when the page is loaded dynamically into that div i can not access to any loaded elements inside of that div using jquery.

data from the get response is the same as below

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$('#menu').empty()
```

```js
$.get('.php?id=get_menu', function(data) 
      {
     $('#menu').append(data);
      });
```

And after load if i click e (edit) jquery do nothing

This a jquery script i using

```js
$('.form').submit(function(event) {
  var $form = $(this);
  var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();
  
  request = $.ajax({
 url: "check.php?id=update_menu",
 type: "post",
 data: serializedData
  });
  
  request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#menu').empty('<div class="preloader-big"></div>');
    $.get('admin_index.php?id=get_menu', function(data) {
  $('#menu').append(data);
    });
  });
  
  request.always(function () {
    $('.preloader-big').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

The php script is output ready to use formated html code

THE ANSWER FOR MY POST

This code gets php datas after clicki'n on the letter e

```js
    $('.optedit').on('click', function() {
     
      $.get('admin_index.php?id=get_menu_edit&mid='+menu_id[1], function(data) {
        
        $('#link_name').val(res[2]);
        $('#link_title').val(res[3]);
        $('#mid').val(res[1]);
        )};
    )};
```

I just pack him into a some function i called her update_menu();
and repeat the function after

```js
$.get('.php?id=get_menu', function(data) {
  $('#menu').append(data);
  update_menu();
})
```

Thats update jquery code to use code that just was added.
Everything works ok.

Thanks for Your help :)

Comment: check whether there is an error thrown with help of your dev-tools.

Comment: I read som articles about it. jquery doesn't see this code in DOM Tree after empty()

Comment: As @ronan says you should use detach if you want to retrieve this data later. Also you should store the data in a variable so it can be retrieved (detach will not recall simple strings, the value must be stored in a variable).

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` removes not only child (and other descendant) elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements.

If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use `.detach()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working here, check your result from .php?id=get_menu

```js
     $('#ammend').on('click',function(){
          $('#menu').append('<ul><li>hello</li><li>there</li></ul>');
          });
$('#empty').on('click',function(){
          $('#menu').empty();
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ammend">Ammend</button>
<button id="empty">Empty</button>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a> <a href="#e">[E]</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem with your code. You have to check the url used in your call `.php?id=get_menu`. This seems incomplete.

Also, you might like to check jQuery's load instead of get to simplify things up.
here's how to use it:

```
$("#menu").load("content_generator.php");
```

And if you want to fire up an event on success:

```
$("#menu").load("content_generator.php", function(){
    console.log("Successful")
});
```

Let me know if this clear things up.

[jQuery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

I paste above my jquery code.
This do the work to contact with php and output some html code